# Converting string to double ERROR OCCURS

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have a gridview

That whenever i click a btn will insert and view in the gridview.

my problem is that i cannot get the sum of the amount

[image: My page image]

this when i add values for the gridview to show

[image: here]

I have a code for getting the SUM of the Amount

```
void GetTotalAmount()
    {
        int GetRefNo;
        decimal GetUnitPrice;

        //GetCart();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount " +
            "FROM PRDetails WHERE POID=@POID";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", Session["userid"].ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POID", POID.Text);
        
        double totalAmount = 0; 
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                totalAmount = int.Parse(dr["TotalAmount"].ToString());
            }
            lbSubTotal.Text = (totalAmount * .88).ToString("#,###.00");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("totalAmount", totalAmount.ToString());
            con.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            lbSubTotal.Text = "0.00";
        }
    //     
        con.Close();
       

    }
```

CODE FOR GRID

```
protected void AddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        decimal price = GetPrice(ID);
        //GetTotalAmount();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PRDetails VALUES (@ProductID, @ProductName, @Price, @Quantity, @Amount, @POID)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", Session["userid"].ToString());
        
        
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", lbProductID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", ddlName.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", decimal.Parse(lbPrice.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Quantity.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", int.Parse(Quantity.Text) * price);
        
        
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POID", POID.Text);
        
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
```

whenever i add products (btn for grid) ERROR occurs : `Input string was not in a correct format.`

`Line 255:                    totalAmount = int.Parse(dr["TotalAmount"].ToString());`

ASP.NET CODES

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
         Width="1000px" AllowPaging="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" PageIndex="20" 
        ShowFooter="True" DataSourceID="details"  >
     <Columns>
       
         <asp:BoundField DataField="POID" HeaderText="POID" 
             SortExpression="POID" />
         
         <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" 
             SortExpression="ProductID" />

         <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" 
             SortExpression="ProductName" />

         <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" 
             SortExpression="Price" />
        
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" 
             SortExpression="Quantity" />

         <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" 
             SortExpression="Amount" />

     </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
 
 
 
 
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="details" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyOwnMeatshopConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [POID], [ProductID], [ProductName], [Price], [Quantity], [Amount] FROM [PRDetails] WHERE ([POID] = @POID)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="POID" Name="POID" PropertyName="Text" 
                Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
 
 
 
 
  <div class="container">
    <div class="pull-right col-lg-5">
        <h5 style="font-weight: bold" />SUB TOTAL Php   <asp:Label ID="lbSubTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

I tried making it int and decimal but doesnt work

what's incomplete with my codes?

please help guys. thank you in advance! still new to c#

Comment: Why you do not debug it to see what you get on the line of error ? Maybe there is nothing a null that can not convert to int. Also its better to use the int.tryparse, but anyway some other must be the bug that send there null value, or who know what. debug debug debug step by step.

Comment: @Aristos i did debug it step by step and line error occurs huhuhu

Comment: Line error occurs, do you see whats is inside that values inside them ? Please read some books, ask some one else to show you how to debug and solve issues. No one else can debug that for you just because you need to find the error on your computer. Also is hard for many to debug that on their mind, but this error is very simple to solve. You have lost more time to write all that, than actually solve it.

Comment: Thanks anyway i've resolved it

Answer (score 0):

Can you change decimal price = GetPrice(ID); to double price = GetPrice(ID);
Sorry, I don't have enough rep to leave a comment.

Comment: still doesn't do anything